# How can I force my terminal to run high resolution in non-X11 environment in Linux?

Tags: linux, terminal, console, grub

I just installed Scientific Linux and I've had a high resolution terminal, then I upgraded my video driver to enable some features of my video card but with that my terminal went to regular resolution 80x25, how can I switch (force) it to use high resolution?

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 Desktop]$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
Scientific Linux release 6.0 (Carbon)
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 Desktop]$ uname -a
Linux wcmisdlin02.uftmasterad.org 2.6.32-71.29.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue May 10 17:35:18 CDT 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 Desktop]$ lsmod 
Module                  Size  Used by
fuse                   66138  0 
ebtable_nat             1975  0 
ebtables               18101  1 ebtable_nat
xt_CHECKSUM             1269  1 
iptable_mangle          3283  1 
ipt_MASQUERADE          2400  3 
iptable_nat             6124  1 
nf_nat                 22788  2 ipt_MASQUERADE,iptable_nat
bridge                 74145  0 
stp                     2107  1 bridge
llc                     5608  2 bridge,stp
autofs4                27683  3 
sunrpc                241630  1 
cpufreq_ondemand       10382  2 
acpi_cpufreq            8625  0 
freq_table              4847  2 cpufreq_ondemand,acpi_cpufreq
xt_physdev              1707  1 
ipt_REJECT              2349  4 
nf_conntrack_ipv4       9440  17 iptable_nat,nf_nat
nf_defrag_ipv4          1449  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
iptable_filter          2759  1 
ip_tables              17733  3 iptable_mangle,iptable_nat,iptable_filter
nf_conntrack_netbios_ns     1630  0 
nf_conntrack_ftp       12911  0 
ip6t_REJECT             4562  2 
nf_conntrack_ipv6      19655  13 
xt_state                1458  27 
nf_conntrack           79643  8 ipt_MASQUERADE,iptable_nat,nf_nat,nf_conntrack_ipv4,nf_conntrack_netbios_ns,nf_conntrack_ftp,nf_conntrack_ipv6,xt_state
ip6table_filter         2855  1 
ip6_tables             19392  1 ip6table_filter
ipv6                  321509  61 ip6t_REJECT,nf_conntrack_ipv6
dm_mirror              14003  0 
dm_region_hash         12200  1 dm_mirror
dm_log                 10088  2 dm_mirror,dm_region_hash
kvm_intel              46653  0 
kvm                   292815  1 kvm_intel
uinput                  8182  0 
ppdev                   8695  0 
parport_pc             22944  0 
parport                37327  2 ppdev,parport_pc
tpm_infineon            9019  0 
wmi                     6221  0 
sg                     30186  0 
serio_raw               4816  0 
iTCO_wdt               11708  0 
iTCO_vendor_support     3022  1 iTCO_wdt
snd_hda_codec_analog    79931  1 
snd_hda_intel          25194  4 
snd_hda_codec          82097  2 snd_hda_codec_analog,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep               6714  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_seq                56557  0 
snd_seq_device          6626  1 snd_seq
snd_pcm                84700  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_timer              23087  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                    70053  16 snd_hda_codec_analog,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_pcm,snd_timer
soundcore               8052  1 snd
snd_page_alloc          8628  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
e1000e                140083  0 
fglrx                2808339  170 
ext4                  353851  2 
mbcache                 7918  1 ext4
jbd2                   89033  1 ext4
sr_mod                 16162  0 
cdrom                  39769  1 sr_mod
sd_mod                 37221  3 
crc_t10dif              1507  1 sd_mod
ata_piix               22588  2 
ata_generic             3611  0 
pata_acpi               3667  0 
dm_mod                 76824  8 dm_mirror,dm_log
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 Desktop]$
```

Comment: You may also want to look into uvesafb/v86d, which can result in native-resolution framebuffers for the console on most cards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the [GRUB vga mode](http://pierre.baudu.in/other/grub.vga.modes.html) to something like `vga=791`. The setting is appended to the end of the `kernel` line in `/etc/grub.conf`.

For example:

```
# grub.conf generated by anaconda
#boot=/dev/sda
default=0
timeout=5
splashimage=(hd0,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
hiddenmenu
title CentOS (2.6.18-194.11.1.el5)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.18-194.11.1.el5 ro root=LABEL=/ vga=791
        initrd /initrd-2.6.18-194.11.1.el5.img
```

Comment: Is there a way to take effect without rebooting? I assume grub requires reboot

Comment: reboot took care of it, but I was wondering if its possible to do it on the fly as well

Comment: Probably not, since it's a kernel boot parameter.